# How to invalidate an IBAction method on touch release

Tags: objective-c, release, ibaction, uitouch, invalidation

Here is the code i am using to try to invalidate the IBActions "TouchEndedLeft" & "TouchEndedRight" on touch release

```
-(IBAction)LeftArrowTapped:(id)sender; {

[self heroMovementTimerMethodLeft];

}

-(IBAction)RightArrowTapped:(id)sender; {

[self heroMovementTimerMethodRight];

}

-(void)heroMovementLeft{

hero.center = CGPointMake(hero.center.x -.5, hero.center.y );

}

-(void)heroMovementRight{

hero.center = CGPointMake(hero.center.x +.5, hero.center.y );

}

-(void)heroMovementTimerMethodLeft {

heroMovementTimerLeft = [NSTimer 
scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speedOfhero 
target:self selector:@selector(heroMovementLeft) userInfo:nil 
repeats:YES];
}

-(void)heroMovementTimerMethodRight {

heroMovementTimerRight = [NSTimer
scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:speedOfhero 
target:self selector:@selector(heroMovementRight) userInfo:nil 
repeats:YES];
}
```

here is how i am trying to invalidate the method using a touch cancelled IBAction style

```
-(IBAction)TouchendedLeft:(id)sender; {

[heroMovementTimerLeft invalidate];

}
-(IBAction)TouchendedRight:(id)sender; {

[heroMovementTimerRight invalidate];

}
```

What is the best way to invalidate an IBAction method when you release your finger? i have tried touch cancelled touch up outside and touch up inside IBAction styles, but none seem to work. Im i using the wrong IBAction style? the wrong method type? or am i executing the code wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you make two IBActions, one for each button desired event, you should be able to capture the touchdown: event and the touchUpInside: event. The initial press should be associated to the touchdown: event and the release of the button with the touchUpInside: event. It sounds like you are trying to make a game, have you looked into SpriteKit(2D) or SceneKit (3D) frameworks?

Comment: it worked! thank you so much! and yes i am making a game i have looked a little into sprite kit 2d for an analog stick and i will be using cocos 2dx for my characters